# jquery slider for html markups

Tags: jquery

There are tons of jquery sliders for images. However I have some html markups like

```
<p>JavaScript rocks</p>
<p>jQuery rocks</p>
<p>stackoverflow rocks</p>
```

Assume each `<p>` is of size 400x400. I want a jquery slider which can slide each p element one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a content slider jQuery plugin which you are looking for, give it a try

**http://bxslider.com/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.0/